# can gnu tar detect changed directory ownership?

Tags: linux, tar

I'm using tar 1.15.1 (CentOS 5.5) to archive a directory.

```
[www]$ tar -tvzf public_org.tgz 'public/files'
drwxrwxr-x root/www          0 2010-12-01 07:33:33 public/files/
-rwxrwxr-x root/www         55 2010-12-01 07:33:33 public/files/dummy.txt
[www]$ ls -ld public/files{,/*}
drwxrwxr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Dec  1 07:33 public/files
-rwxrwxr-x 1 apache apache   55 Dec  1 07:33 public/files/dummy.txt
[www]$ tar -dvzf public_org.tgz 'public/files'
public/files/
public/files/dummy.txt
public/files/dummy.txt: Uid differs
public/files/dummy.txt: Gid differs
```

Anybody know why I don't get Uid/Gid differs messages on the directory? I'd really like to know if any permissions changed.

I tried running as both normal user and root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  I saw the same behavior with tar-1.15-1 on Centos 5.5.  I took a look at the source, and it apparently doesn't diff directories, as you observed.

I compiled up the most recent version (1.26) and tried that.  Same behavior.

I'm not sure what, if any rationale there is behind this.  There could be a good one, I suppose, or maybe it's just something that they haven't implemented yet.  You might try asking on the [tar help mailing list](http://savannah.gnu.org/mail/?group=tar)